# PackageManager.getInstallerPackageName returns com.google.android.packageinstaller, what does it mean?

Tags: android

We are using https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstallerPackageName(java.lang.String) to obtain package info. Most of the times we get `com.android.vending` back, but in some cases we are seeing `com.google.android.packageinstaller`. In what cases PM will return this string? Was the app sideloaded from somewhere?

Comment: I am not sure, but I would gess you get com.android.vending if the app was installed via the Playstore and com.google.android.packageinstaller if the apk was installed directly.

Comment: yup, that is my hypothesis, but I wasn't able to find any docs in that regard :(